# Module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util.. Compile time error

Tags: java, android-studio

Getting this error while building the shadowsocks project.

(https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android)

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext (in unnamed module @0x1d312b6c)
cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context (in module jdk.compiler)
because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x1d312b6c
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.(KaptContext.kt:28)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did your issue got resolved ? @Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when running an old app. My original kotlin version was 1.3.72 and i updated it to 1.8.21 and my problem was solved.

Comment: What was your original Kotlin version and what version did you update to?

Comment: My original kotlin version was 1.3.72 and i updated it to 1.8.21

Comment: [Edit] your answer and add the details. Don't post answer details in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

More descriptive solution:

1. Go to `build.gradle` file
2. In the module config, for the Kotlin implementation, make sure it reflects the latest plugin [image: Module build.gradle file]
3. Android Studio will highlight, describe the issue & suggest a correct version
4. Edit it an build again
5. In my case the Kotlin version is specified in the Project's `build.gradle` file

[image: Project build.gradle file]

Comment: I am having the same exact problem with the same project (testing codelab), i have tried changing kotlinVersion to 1.8.2 (recommended by the IDE) but this did not work

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem by updating kotlin version in android studio but not changing buildscript `{ ext.kotlin_version = 'specify new version here'}` in build gradle